# EWS FindItems vs FindAppointments different data returns?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have tried getting data from user calendar using EWS. First time I used FindItems with search filter (from - to dates), I noticed that some of user calendar items were not retrieved. I checked these items and I found out that the user not in attendees, but he is a member of a group in attendees.

I turned my code to use FindAppointments and I got these missing items correctly, but I also got cancelled and non accepted meetings which were not returned with FindItems. I have googled this issue with no specific result. I need to know why this happens and when should I use FindItems and FindAppointments?

Code with finditems

```
SearchFilter fromFilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, eventSearch.From);
SearchFilter toFilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, eventSearch.To);
SearchFilter inRangeFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, fromFilter, toFilter);

FindItemsResults<Item> results = EXService.FindItems(
         new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, eventSearch.UserEmail),
         inRangeFilter, view);
```

Code with FindAppointments

```
 FolderId folderid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(roomEmail));
 FindItemsResults<Appointment> results = EXService.FindAppointments(folderid,
                new CalendarView(sDate, eDate));
```